# Cast one class into another identical class

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I added two Web Services that created several identical classes in two different namespaces. Example:

```
namespace NS1
{
    class SomeClass
    {
        ...
    }

    class AnotherClass
    {
        NS1.SomeClass SomeVariable = new NS1.SomeClass();
    }
}

namespace NS2
{
    class SomeClass
    {
        ...
    }

    class AnotherClass
    {
        NS2.SomeClass SomeVariable = new NS2.SomeClass();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to cast NS1.AnotherClass into NS2.AnotherClass? Or better yet, is it possible to add a Web Service reference so that it doesn't duplicate classes already existing in other added Web Services?

Comment: Side note: you may want to ask second question separately.

Answer (score 3):

No. Although they look similar, these classes have nothing in common. Write a converter or share an interface or a base class.

Another option is to write a wrapper that does share a base class, much like `System.Web.HttpContextWrapper`, but it requires tunnelling all methods you want to expose through the wrapper class. Resharper can help here.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot cast one class to another if they do not inherit from each other (directly or indirectly).

In your particular case (using webservices) you can force the wizard to create one and the same class (there is a checkbox to reuse existing classes).

Answer (score 2):

You can use WDSL.exe to generate your proxies, instead of Visual Studio. WSDL.exe has a command-line switch to share types:

> **/shareTypes**
>   Turns on the type sharing feature. This feature creates one code file
>   with a single type definition for identical types shared between
>   different services (the namespace, name, and wire signature must be
>   identical). Reference the services with "http://" URLs as command-line
>   parameters or create a discomap document for local files. When using
>   the /parameters option, this value is the  element and is
>   either true or false.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28vs.80%29.aspx)

You can access WSDL.exe from the Visual Studio Command Prompt. An example command would look like:

```
wsdl.exe /sharetypes http://service1.com http://service2.com
```

**Update**

If you want to be able to share types across web services using the Visual Studio and the "Add Service Reference" method, you can do so with a .disco file. First you would need to create a .disco file that lists the locations of all the WSDL files you would like to include. Here is an example:

```
<discovery xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <contractRef xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/scl/" ref="http://<url to wsdl1>"/>  
  <contractRef xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/scl/" ref="http://<url to wsdl2>"/>
</discovery>
```

Next, in the Visual Studio Add Service Reference dialog you can put in the path to the .disco file you just created prefixed with "file://". So if the file were named service.disco saved in c:\temp, you would use **file://c:\temp\service.disco** as the address.

Comment: Nice, but it renamed the classes to e.g. "AnotherClass" and "AnotherClass1" etc.

Comment: Are the two types in the same XML Namespace in your code? Are you using asmx or wcf services?

Comment: They are two WSDL files on my hard drive, downloaded from https://github.com/jzempel/fedex/tree/master/fedex/wsdls Linking the local files in the .disco file recognized all the services but created copies of each class.

Comment: I'll give it a try on those wsdl files. Can you give me an example of a class that is not being named as expected?

Comment: Thanks! WebAuthenticationDetail is one class that gets renamed.

Comment: If you look at the code generated, you will see that each of those is defined in a separate XML namespace. This API is explicitly declaring that even though the types have similar names, they are not intended to be the same across services. This is quite unfortunate since most of the time the types are identical across all services. There are a few cases where they are not though. For example AdditionalLabelsType.

Answer (score 2):

In analogy to "duck typing", I wrote a "duck copy" method:

```
public class DuckCopy
{
    public static void CopyFields(object source, object target)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (target == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("target");

        FieldInfo[] fiSource = source.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        FieldInfo[] fiTarget = target.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        foreach (FieldInfo fiS in fiSource)
        {
            foreach (FieldInfo fiT in fiTarget)
            {
                if (fiT.Name == fiS.Name)
                {
                    fiT.SetValue(target, fiS.GetValue(source));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like

```
NS1.AnotherClass input = ...;
NS2.AnotherClass output = new NS2.AnotherClass();
DuckCopy.CopyFields(input, output);
```